# Slideshow does not show on the homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I have just installed `Magento 1.9.1` as an upgrade from `1.7` and thought the slideshow would automatically display on homepage with the `rwd/default` package/theme.

Is there code that I am supposed to add to a file to display the slideshow?

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you are using different CMS Page for showing your home page.

By default `Magento 1.9.1` uses `Madison Island` home page and you can find the banner code inside this page. So login into your admin and go to `CMS > Pages > Madson Island` and in `content` section you can find the code corresponding to banner section.

In your case, you either need to set `Madison Island` as your home page in order to view the banner. If your site is a production site and you are using another CMS Page, then you need to adapt the same method which is used in the default home page. If you are using any other custom blocks to show your home page, then again you need to look into the code available there and then implement it in your own custom block.

This is what I can see inside Madison Island home page.

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <ul class="slideshow">
        <li><a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}accessories/eyewear.html"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slide-1.jpg"}}" alt="An eye for detail - Click to Shop Eye Wear" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}women.html"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slide-2.jpg"}}" alt="Style solutions - covet-worthy styles in travel-friendly fabrics - Click to Shop Woman" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}men.html"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slide-3.jpg"}}" alt="Wing man - hit the runway in stylish separates and casuals - Click to Shop Man" /></a></li>
        </ul>
<div class="slideshow-pager">&nbsp;</div>
<span class="slideshow-prev">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next">&nbsp;</span></div>

<ul class="promos">
    <li>
        <a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}home-decor.html"> 
            <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/homepage-three-column-promo-01B.png"}}" alt="Physical &amp; Virtual Gift Cards" /> 
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}vip.html"> 
            <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/homepage-three-column-promo-02.png"}}" alt="Shop Private Sales - Members Only" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}accessories/bags-luggage.html"> 
            <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/homepage-three-column-promo-03.png"}}" alt="Travel Gear for Every Occasion" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Rajeev...Thank you so much for helping me resolve the problem. My installation of Magento 1.9.1 using the default rwd package and theme did not include the above information in the content section of the CMS>Pages>Homepage.  Additionally, I don't see a home page that is labeled as "Madison Island" to enable.  Also, my install of 1.9.1 did not create a media folder labeled "wysiwyg" automatically. Does the media file get overwritten during upcoming upgrades to Magento? If so, should I move the slide images to my skin/rwd/default/images/media folder so they won't be deleted during upgrade?

Comment: "Madison Island" home page and "wysiwyg" media folders comes with sample data for Magento 1.9.1. So it will not be available for you in the upgraded version. You have two possibiliy to resolve this. 1) create your own extension that adds a banner in home page 2) locally install a new Magento 1.9.1 with sample data and then follow the steps that use in default case. In either way you need to dig more.

Comment: Thank you so much Rajeev.  The information you shared helped me solve my problem.  You're the best!!!